# present perfect in this case

Tags: present-perfect

> Punk Slime Recordings are proud to present our latest signing Mind Rays alongside the lead single from their debut album Nerve Endings. The Belgian garage punk quartet **have** quickly **emerged** as one of the most exciting new garage acts in mainland Europe, and with Nerve Endings they’re set to take over the world. Lead single “Still & All” is out now and the full-length will be arriving on March 24 via PNKSLM Recordings.

Why present perfect?  Does that mean they are still emerging or means they finished recently emerging? I think the last proposition is the best.

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect means that the event described are in the past, but have present relevance. This present relevance often means that the results of the event are still continuing (though it can have other meanings). With an inchoative  verb like "emerge", the present relevance is nearly always that whatever it is is still visible.

So "They have emerged" usually means "They started to be seen and are still visible". "They emerged" would often imply "They started to be seen, but are no longer visible".

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it means

> they have been and still are emerging

"Emerged" is being used to mean "become"

> The Belgian garage punk quartet have quickly *become* one of the most exciting...

The band is still an "exciting new garage act" (hopefully).

Comment: I don't think it means they are "still emerging" -- they're all the way out!

Comment: No, it doesn't necessarily mean that they are still emerging, but that they are still visible. They might still be emerging, or they might have come fully into the light.

Comment: They "are set to take over the world", but they haven't taken over yet! Granted, they have emerged as a *new* band, so they may be on that cusp! Does this look like an established band to you? [Mind Rays (live) - Iron Muide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le3fuIeWVVo), kind of reminds me of The Ramones at CBGB's... but the venue is too "clean", but a good question and nicer way to mark the [40th anniversary of Punk](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-38120496)